# Why does camel route give Failed to send reply with payload error after calling the Message Consumption Listener?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I have defined a camel route in my file route builder like this :

```
from("timer:first-timer") .bean(new MsgConsumptionListener(),"receiveMessage")
            .log(">>>> Body content is  ::::::::   ---> ${body}")
            .log(">>> Name is ::::::: ------> ${body.Name}") 
            .setHeader("Name",method(MsgConsumptionListener.class))
            .to("log:first-timer");
```

Inside the MsgConsumptionListener.java , I am consuming the message like this :

```
    @Async
    @JmsListener(destination = "MyQueue")
    public String receiveMessage(final Message jsonMessage) throws JMSException {
        String messageData = null;
        log.info("Message has been received----->" +jsonMessage);
        String rcvrName = null;
        if(jsonMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)jsonMessage;
            messageData = textMessage.getText();
            Map map = new Gson().fromJson(messageData, Map.class);
            rcvrName  = (String) map.get("Name");
            log.info("Receiver Name----->" +rcvrName);
        }
        return rcvrName;
    }
```

I can see the message is getting consumed , but the camel route gives the below error when it calls the listener :

```
    c.f.i.listener.MsgConsumptionListener         : Message has been received----->ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, destination = queue://MyQueue, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1644257093499, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1644257093500, brokerOutTime = 1644298154164, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@4d7cdcac, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 1, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = {"Name":"Kunal"}}

    c.f.i.listener.MsgConsumptionListener         : Receiver Name----->Kunal
    [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Routes startup summary (total:1 started:1)
    [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   :     Started route1 (timer://first-timer)
    [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.11.2 (camel-1) started in 724ms (build:72ms init:622ms start:30ms)
    o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.

    org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ReplyFailureException: Failed to send reply with payload [bp_exchange.in]; nested exception is javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Cannot determine response destination: Request message does not contain reply-to destination, and no default response destination set.
    [r://first-timer] c.f.i.listener.FileEventListener         : Message has been received----->null
    [r://first-timer] route1                                   : >>> 
    [r://first-timer] c.f.i.listener.FileEventListener         : Message has been received----->null
    [r://first-timer] route1                                   : >>> The file Name set in the header is : 
    [r://first-timer] c.f.i.listener.FileEventListener         : Message has been received----->null
```

So the camel route is not able to get the message attribute Name and set it in the header .
**Does anybody know as to what the issue is and what I should be doing to get the message attribute in the route ?**

**My objective is to** use the file route builder to call my MsgConsumption listener and whenever a message is dropped in the queue , I want the route to trigger the listener , consume the message and get the attribute Name from the message to be used for further processing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Spring JMS expert, but it appears you are mixing Spring JMS listener behavior with Camel route behavior in a way that won't work. If I understand your objective above, you want the route to pick up the queued message and process it. If that's true, I recommend not using Spring JMS listener and also remove the from(timer) in your route and change it to [from(activemq)](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/activemq-component.html) and take the logic in your current listener that examines the message and extracts the name and put that in a bean that the route calls. Like:

```
from("activemq:myqueue")
.bean(GetTheNameBean)
.to("log:message")
```